# Is it possible to get App Pool recycle error?

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have process named agent.exe, my app pool runs 2 instances of this process.

When recycle my AppPool then most of the times it works and those 2 instances are shutting down and 2 new instances are up.

but sometimes when I recycle my 2 old instances aren't shutting down while my 2 new instances are up and working, so I can have 4,6 and even more instances running.

Can I see why the instances aren't been recycled? I only found this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735206(v=ws.10).aspx, but those are only informative logs and I can't see errors in them.

Does anyone know way to see recycling errors logs?

My server is Windows 2003 and I'm running IIS6.
It should be noted that there is no connection to "Overlapping recycling" because the instances don't shutting down at all.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following logs that can use to identify App Pool recycle errors:

> AppPoolRecycleTime - Logs event on time-based recycles.
>   AppPoolRecycleRequests - Logs event on number of request-based
>   recycles.   AppPoolRecycleSchedule - Logs event on schedule-based
>   recycless.   AppPoolRecycleMemory - Logs event on memory-based
>   recycle.   AppPoolRecycleIsapiUnhealthy - Logs event when worker
>   processes request recycles because an ISAPI reported unhealthy.
>   AppPoolRecycleOnDemand - Logs event when an administrator requests a
>   recycle of all processes in the application pool.
>   AppPoolRecycleConfigChange - Logs an event if an application pool is
>   recycled because one of the application pool properties that requires
>   a recycle to take effect has changed.   AppPoolRecyclePrivateMemory -
>   Logs an event if an application pool is recycled based on private
>   memory.

taken from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/87892589-4eda-4003-b4ac-3879eac4bf48.mspx?mfr=true